# Creating a .zip backup using VBS, without hard-coded Wait timer (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, zip, backup

I'm having an issue populating a created .zip folder (used for backing up **everything** from `C:\Source` to a .zip located in `C:\Destination`). The issue arises in the `ZipCMD.vbs` file. I'll describe my whole process now, and at the end, in bold, I'll describe the issue, and my attempted (and failed) solutions.

There exists a folder containing test data, in `C:\Source`

In `C:\Destination`, create `ZipCMD.vbs` using the following code in Notepad (Credit to Gerhard Barnard)

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
InputFolder = FS.GetAbsolutePathName(objArgs(0))
ZipFile = FS.GetAbsolutePathName(objArgs(1))

CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items

objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source)
WScript.Sleep 3000
```

I've also created a `Backups.bat` in `C:\Destination` using the following code in Notepad

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%
set stamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%%HH%%Min%
rem Parameters set for use later


ZipCMD.vbs "C:\Source" "C:\Destination\BackupTest1.zip"
rem This line copies all files and folders from the Source to the Destination into a named .zip, without a date, by utilising the VBS created earlier.

Del "C:\Destination\*_BackupTest1.zip"
rem This line deletes the old backup (All **final** backups are named using 'YYYYMMDDhhmm_BackupTest1.zip'). The '_' prevents this command deleting the newly-created zip from before.

Rename C:\Destination\BackupTest1.zip %Stamp%_BackupTest1.zip
rem Renames newly-created zip file with datestamp and underscore (for information, and so that it can be identified for deletion next time this is run).

Set File="*_BackupTest1.zip"
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%file%') DO set size=%%~zA
rem These lines define a new parameter defined by the created .zip's size

Echo %stamp%%Sec%   %stamp%_BackupTest1.zip %Size%>>BackupLog.log
rem This last line appends a line to a log file containing the time the zip was created, the name of the .zip created, and its' size.
```

The second section of the above .bat (after defining initial parameters) can be repeated for multiple folders, but changing 'Source' each time.

Lastly, I create a `RunBackups.vbs` in `C:\Destination` using the following code in Notepad

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell" ) 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\[SyncFolder]\Backups.bat" & Chr(34), 0 
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

This runs the .bat without having the black CMD window appear (i.e. running in 'silent' mode), and is the file I call upon using Task Scheduler to automate the backup process.

**Problem:** The `WScript.Sleep 3000` line in `ZipCMD.vbs` is a bodge. If the entire .zip file can be created in <3 seconds, great. Otherwise, we've got a non-functional backup. Extending this timer can prove problematic for larger or multiple backups.

- Solution attempt #1: In `ZipCMD.vbs`, replacing the 3000 wait, start a loop that checks whether a .zip has been created with name=ZipFile. This creates a .zip with the correct name, but contains no data (i.e. The backup process has created a .zip, but vbs has closed before it had a chance to populate any data/files)
- Solution attempt #2: In `ZipCMD.vbs`, replacing the 3000 wait, count the number of files in Source, and wait (loop) until the .zip contains that number of files, with a 500ms delay between each check. Problem: This works perfectly for all files except the last one to be copied. If the last file can be copied in <500ms, this works. Otherwise, the last file doesn't get copied. Extending this timer can prove problematic for backups containing very large files.

**Question:** What can I replace the 'Wait' timer with, to ensure that the .zip is created fully each time (without just setting a massive timer), without using any non-default-windows functionality? (i.e. non-third-party (e.g. 7zip))

I've heard that Java/Javascript (?) might get around this issue, but am unsure how/if this would work? (due to limited technical knowledge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this modified ZipCMD.vbs

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
InputFolder = FS.GetAbsolutePathName(objArgs(0))
ZipFile = FS.GetAbsolutePathName(objArgs(1))

CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items

numfolderitems = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items.count

objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source)

' wait until number of items in zip file is the same as in the folder we are zipping up
' also sometimes gets errors when getting folder object for zip file, probably because it is in use? so ignore these
On Error Resume Next
Do while True
    numitemsinzip = objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).Items.count
    If Err.Number = 0 and numitemsinzip = numfolderitems Then
        Exit Do
    ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 then
        Err.Clear
    End If
    wScript.Sleep 10
Loop
On Error Goto 0
```

This is basically your solution #2 of waiting until the zip file has all the items in it except I had to make it ignore errors that it would get occasionally. I tested it a few times and it seems to work OK. The only potential issue would be if the zipping operation gets stopped for some reason then the wscript.exe process would just run forever because all the files would never be put in the zip file.

Comment: This has actually worked! But when creating larger .zip files, the compression interface appears. Is there a way for this to not happen? (i.e. for the compression process to happen in the background?)

Comment: Sorry the [documentation for copyhere](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866(v=vs.85).aspx) has flags to hide the progress dialog but they do not appear to work for zip files for some reason.

Comment: Fair enough. Follow up question: Is it possible somehow to have the number of files copied into the .zip counted (for use in recording in the .log file)? e.g. `Set FileCount = CountOfFilesZipped` and then later `Echo %FileCount%` -- If so, how would I implement that? -- **A 'count' of files within the .zip post-creation would work for this purpose**

Comment: Look at the beginning of the ZipCMD.vbs where it is writing "PK" ... etc to the empty zip file. You can use the same code to write CountOfFilesZipped to a file. But that is really only the number of items (files and folders) copied to the root of the zip file. It would not include files in folders/subfolders/etc... not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: Preferably the number would include all files in folders/subfolders/etc. Additionally, when I said 'for use in recording in the .log file', I meant if it was possible to have it in the same log entry as `Echo %stamp%%Sec%   %stamp%_BackupTest1.zip %Size%>>BackupLog.log` (from the .bat file),
i.e. each log entry would have: `Date/Time, ZipName, FileCount, Size`